# Is there an algorithm for fuzzy search like Levenshtein Distance specialised for a set of ordered character?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, set, edit-distance

I found an algorithm (on https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance) and after reading a bit more about levenshtein, I understood there should be a better way of telling the edit distance of twwo strings if these strings are strictly composed of ascii-aphabetically ordered and unique chars.

Meaning, for every a and b like a < b, a will be prior to b, and the reciprocal (or contraposed or I don't remember) for every a, b, and c like a < b < c, if one strings reads ac and the other ab, one knows for sure the first one does not contain the b.

And that precisely means there is a better way of determining the edit distance between two strings of this kind.

If it is any useful, the class I'm using to organize my characters is a TreeSet of Character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with :
I used it with values :
String tested, String target, 1, 0.

```
/** returns the cost of the difference between a tested CharSequence and a target CharSequence. CS = CharSequence
 * @param tested input, the CS which will be compared to the target. all letters sorted by ASCII order and unique
 * @param target is the CS to which the tested will be compared. all letters sorted by ASCII order and unique
 * @param positiveDifferenceCost is the cost to add when a letter is in the tested CS but not in the target.
 * @param negativeDifferenceCost is the cost to add when a letter is in the target CS but not in the tested.
 * @return int the number of differences.
 */


public static int oneSidedOAUDistance(final CharSequence tested, final CharSequence target,
                                      final int positiveDifferenceCost, final int negativeDifferenceCost) {
    int diffCount = 0;
    int index_tested = 0;
    int index_target = 0;

    if (positiveDifferenceCost == 0 && negativeDifferenceCost == 0)
        return 0;


    for (; index_tested < tested.length() && index_target < target.length(); ) {
        if (tested.charAt(index_tested) == target.charAt(index_target)) {
            ++index_tested;
            ++index_target;
            continue;
        }
        if (tested.charAt(index_tested) < target.charAt(index_target)) {
            //some letters should not be there in tested string.
            diffCount+= positiveDifferenceCost;
            index_tested++;

        } else {
            //some letters miss in tested string.
            diffCount+=negativeDifferenceCost;
            index_target++;
        }
    }


    return diffCount;
}
```